# Why would openfiles /query only work once in a while?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-server-2008

I'm using `openfiles /query /v` to locate opened files on Windows Server 2008, connecting as an administrator via remote desktop.

openfiles only returns a list of open files about once in every half dozen tries, and then irregularly. I may get two or three successful commands in a row, then nothing for eight or ten attempts.

Since I'd like to filter the list for files that may or may not be open, the current behavior isn't very useful.

Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I never did find out why openfiles wouldn't work reliably. I ended up using [SysInternals Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) and a Powershell script to filter the output.